# Why classes change the order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$("body").on("click", ".close", function() {
  var class_test1 = 'class1 class2';
  var class_test2 = 'class1 class3';
  $('#id_test').removeClass(class_test1).addClass(class_test2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id_test" class="class1 class2">
  test
</div>
<button class="close">
  test
</button>
```

If click on button, `div#id_test` should be change classes on `class1 class3`, but he change classes on `class3 class1`(classes change the order).
Why is this happening and have resolved problem?

P.S.: need change `class1 class3` on `class1 class2` - only in this order.

Comment: since you're just adding/removing `class2` and `class3`, why not toggling only them?

Comment: because it is necessary to do exactly as I wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the following:

There are multiple classes overlapping with multiple clicks.
Let me explain:

When you click the button the first time, the classes "class1" and "class2" get removed. Then "class1" and "class3" gets attached.

However, if you click the button AGAIN, ONLY "class1" gets removed, making "class3" move to the first position (since there is no "class2" to remove anymore). Then "class1" gets re-added AFTER "class3" - resulting in "class3 class1".

Suggested solution:

```
$("body").on("click", ".close", function() {
  var class_test2 = 'class1 class3';
  $('#id_test').removeClass().addClass(class_test2);
});
```

This will remove ALL the classes and then adds the right ones in right order.

Comment: but `div#id_test` can be have other classes and it remove their too

Comment: Assuming that is a problem, you can just use this code instead to get all of them off at once: $('#id_test').removeClass('class1 class2 class3');

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-function-state) to toggle `2` , `3` at end of one of the `className` string

```js
$("body").on("click", ".close", function() {
  var n = 3;
  $("#id_test").toggleClass(function() {
    return "class2 class" + n;
  })
});
```

```css
#id_test.class2 {
  color: green;
}
#id_test.class3 {
  color: blue;
}
#id_test.class2:after {
  content: attr(class);
}
#id_test.class3:after {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="id_test" class="class1 class2">
  test
</div>
<button class="close">
  test
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(".close").on("click", function() {
  $('#id_test').removeClass("class2").addClass("class3");
});
```

Comment: It can be `$('#id_test').toggleClass('class2 class3');`

Comment: @itsgoingdown yes. my main question bad(. Unfortunately i wrote before my thoughts, and i can not delete question now.